# Cannot use a different Linux Kernel in Arch/Manjaro

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, manjaro

I just successfully installed a new Linux kernel (5.3), but at boot I do not have the option to select it. Am I missing any further steps?

This what I get querying the system for the available kernels:

```
> mhwd-kernel -li
Currently running: 5.2.20-1-MANJARO (linux52)
The following kernels are installed in your system:
   * linux52
   * linux53
```

However GRUB only shows me linux52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually have to run:

```
> sudo update-grub
```